# Why does static_cast(*this) to a base class create a temporary copy?

Tags: c++, casting, effective-c++

I'm reading *Effective C++* and came across this example:

```
class Window {                                // base class
public:
  virtual void onResize() { ... }             // base onResize impl
  ...
};

class SpecialWindow: public Window {          // derived class
public:
  virtual void onResize() {                   // derived onResize impl;
    static_cast<Window>(*this).onResize();    // cast *this to Window,
                                              // then call its onResize;
                                              // this doesn't work!

    ...                                       // do SpecialWindow-
  }                                           // specific stuff

  ...

};
```

The book says:

> What you might not expect is that it does not invoke that function on the current object! Instead, the cast creates a new, temporary copy of the base class part of *this, then invokes onResize on the copy!

Why does static_cast (above code) create a new copy? Why not just just use the base class part of the object?

Comment: If it was cast to `static_cast<Window&>(*this).onResize();`, then I think it would use the current object. (Note the `&`). Not sure though.

Comment: static_cast<Window*>(this)->onResize();
should also work but of course
    Window::onResize();
is the correct one here.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Because this code *asks* to create a new object. This code wants to make a `Window` object from `*this` — which can be done using the ***copy constructor*** of `Window`.

What you want instead is this:

```
static_cast<Window&>(*this).onResize(); 
//                ^
//                note the &
```

This means I want to make a `Window&` from `*this` — which is an ***implicit conversion from a*** derived class' ***reference*** (`*this` is a `SpecialWindow&`) to a `Window&` reference.

However, it's better to just ***call the specific version of the member function*** `onResize()` you want to call:

```
Window::onResize(); // equivalent to this->Window::onResize();
```

Comment: *'Why not just just use the base class part of the object?'* – wouldn't be the true answer *'Because the standard specifies that way!'*? It *could* do differently, but that's what we need to live with – for good or for bad (actually it broke an attempt of mine to solve a problem via function pointers to virtual base member function, which made me stumble upon here...).

Answer (score 8):

That's because the code is casting to a value `Window` instead of a reference `Window&`. According to the standard, this form of casting is equivalent to calling (C++11 §5.2.9/4 = C++03 §5.2.9/2)

```
Window __t (*this);
__t.onResize();
```

which invokes the copy-constructor of `Window`, and performs onResize on that copy.

(The proper way of calling a method of the superclass is

```
Window::onResize();
```

)

Answer (score 2):

Because you are casting actual object not a pointer or reference.
It's just the same way casting `double` to `int` creates new `int` - not reusing the part of `double`.

Answer (score 1):

Contrast:

```
static_cast<Window>(*this)
```

with:

```
static_cast<Window&>(*this)
```

One calls the copy constructor, the other does not.  Does that help?